# ANTLR lexer for C-style comment

Tags: regex, parsing, antlr, grammar, lexer

I'm currently working on a ANTLR lexer rule of supporting C-style comment. There has been a widely recommended rule for such a goal:

```
C_COMMENT
:
'/*' (options {greedy=false;}: .)* '*/'
{ $channel=HIDDEN; }
;
```

However what I want is an alternative: '+' is not allowed to be the first non-space character of the comment body, e.g. /* +blablabla*/ is not a valid comment.
Then I tried something like this:

```
C_COMMENT
:
'/*' (' '|'\r'|'\t'|'\n')* ~(' '|'\r'|'\t'|'\n'|'+') (options {greedy=false;}: .)* '*/'
{ $channel=HIDDEN; }
;
```

And it nearly worked, except for empty comments /* */. So I tried something like this:

```
C_COMMENT
:
'/*' (' '|'\r'|'\t'|'\n')*
(
'*/'
|
(~(' '|'\r'|'\t'|'\n'|'+') (options {greedy=false;}: .)* '*/')
)
{ $channel=HIDDEN; }
;
```

It, and a bunch of similar ones that I didn't list, never worked. The * / in /* */ always falls into ~(' '|'\r'|'\t'|'\n'|'+') part.

Finally I got something working like this:

```
C_COMMENT
:
'/*' (' '|'\r'|'\t'|'\n')* '*/'
{ $channel=HIDDEN; }
|
'/*' (' '|'\r'|'\t'|'\n')*
(
'*/'
|
(~(' '|'\r'|'\t'|'\n'|'+') (options {greedy=false;}: .)* '*/')
)
{ $channel=HIDDEN; }
;
```

Though ANTLR warns that patterns like /* */ can match both alternatives.

Could anyone help me to understand all of this? I mean, why nothing above the last one worked.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not do something like this:

```
grammar T;

parse
 : ( c_comment
   | plus_comment
   )* 
   EOF
 ;

c_comment
 : C_COMMENT
 ;

plus_comment
 : PLUS_COMMENT
 ;

PLUS_COMMENT
 : '/*' S* '+' .* '*/'
 ;

C_COMMENT
 : '/*' .* '*/'
 ;

SPACES
 : S+ {skip();}
 ;

fragment S
 : ' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n'
 ;
```

which will parse the input:

```
/**/
/*       + as*/
/*  sdcdcds      sdcds */
```

as follows:

[image]

The trick here is to define `PLUS_COMMENT` ***before*** `C_COMMENT`. That way, if the lexer stumbles on `"/*  s"`, it falls back from a `PLUS_COMMENT` to a `C_COMMENT` because it cannot match the `+`.

Comment: Hi Bart, thanks for the answer. My apology that I didn't address my question fully. The reason why I didn't make /*+ ... * / a lexer rule is that there is a legacy parser rule of /*+ ... * /. So my point is to handle /* ... * / (... starts with non-'+' character) in lexer and let /*+ ... * / still hit the parser, in which there are sub-rules for the content between /*+ and * /. So I still want to focus on my pervious question about why "The * / in /* * / always falls into ~(' '|'\r'|'\t'|'\n'|'+') part."

Comment: I don't understand. You can still put `C_COMMENT` on the `HIDDEN` channel while letting `PLUS_COMMENT` hit the parser.

Comment: I mean, the .* in PLUS_COMMENT implies another parser rule. I'm not sure how to abstract the .* part and let the parser rule handle it.

Comment: My advice is to write a separate grammar for whatever is inside `/* + ... */` (and tokenize it as a single token  as I suggested). Trying to handle whatever is inside your `PLUS` comment (and trying to let `C_COMMENT` *not* match optional spaces and a `+` at the start) makes it a true mess. Making it work would involve custom (Java) code and a predicate: it will not work as you're trying to do now. Perhaps ANTLRv4's lexer can handle it without custom code? Good luck!

Comment: Yes Bart, I think I will leave it as it is now, until we move on to V4 someday. Thanks for your help. Really appreciate that.